# Differential Equation $y'=\dfrac{1-y^2}{x}, x > 0$

Tags: analysis

Consider differential equation:

$$y'=\dfrac{1-y^2}{x},   x > 0$$

Determine all solutions $y \in C(0,+ \infty)$ with $-1 < y < 1$

**What I have tried:**

First write equation as:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1-y^2}{x}$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{1-y^2}=\dfrac{dx}{x}$$
Then, we integrate:

$$ \int \dfrac{dy}{1-y^2}=\int \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

Then, after integration we have:

$$\dfrac{1}{2} ln \left ( \dfrac{y+1}{1-y} \right )=ln(x)$$

Then, what should I do to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did well, except your last equation should have a $+c$ at the end. Anyway, now, we solve for $y$: 
$$\ln(\frac{1+y}{1-y})=2\ln(x)+c$$
$$\frac{1+y}{1-y}=ce^{2\ln(x)} = cx^2$$
$$y = \frac{cx^2-1}{cx^2+1}$$
This is always defined on all of $\Bbb{R}$. We want to find out, for which values of $c$, we have $-1<y<1$ for all $x>0$. But for positive $x$ this holds for any $c$.

Comment: You must also find the "singular solutions" - in this case, $y = 1$ (which is not in the family of solutions parameterized by $c$ but satisfies the original equation).